"startIndex cannot be larger than length of string": strange error during consuming Unity nuget package
I use Package Manager Console to install Unity package into my legacy projects in .NET Framework 4.5.2 that are placed in c:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\SomeFolder\SomeInnerFolder2\ParticularSolutionFolder. I use this command:
  Install-Package -ProjectName $ProjectName -Id Unity -Version 2.1.505.2 -Source nuget.org -Verbose -FileConflictAction IgnoreAll -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction Ignore -IncludePrerelease

All is good, it works well. Now I want to change repositoryPath in nuget.config to install all packages for all my solutions into the same folder. I add the below lines to nuget.config:
<config>
   <add key="repositoryPath" value="c:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages" />
</config>

Mostly it works well too, but Unity packages gives me the below output and fails.
At first it works normally:
    Added package 'Unity.2.1.505.2' to folder 'c:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages' from source '
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
    Added reference 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' to project:'X'. The Reference was Resolved To Package (resolvedToPackage):'True', where Reference Path from DTE(dteOriginalPath):'C:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\lib\NET35\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll' and Reference Path from package reference(assemblyFullPath):'c:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\lib\NET35\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll'.
    Added reference 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity' to project:'X'. The Reference was Resolved To Package (resolvedToPackage):'True', where Reference Path from DTE(dteOriginalPath):'C:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\lib\NET35\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll' and Reference Path from package reference(assemblyFullPath):'c:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\lib\NET35\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll'.
    Added package 'Unity.2.1.505.2' to 'packages.config'

but then fails with the below error:
    Executing script file 'c:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\tools\install.ps1'
    Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
    Parameter name: startIndex"
    At C:\%SOLUTION_BASE_PATH%\packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\tools\Utils.psm1:71 char:12
    +     return ($targetPath.Substring($basePath.Length)).TrimStart([Syste ...
    +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Then it just removes affected packages:
    Removed package 'Unity.2.1.505.2 : CommonServiceLocator [1.0.0, )' from 'packages.config'
    Removed reference 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll' from project 'X'
    Removed reference 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll' from project 'X'
    Removed package 'CommonServiceLocator.1.0.0' from 'packages.config'
    ...

and fails the whole run:
    ...
    Executing nuget actions took 5.91 sec
    The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

It happens only on my work machine, so when I try it on another one it doesn't give any issues, so I can check the content inside the package that fails. The failed file has just these lines:
    param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

    Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath Utils.psm1)

    $relativeInstallPath = Get-RelativePath ([System.Io.Path]::GetDirectoryName($dte.Solution.FullName)) $installPath

    $folder = (Join-Path (Join-Path $relativeInstallPath "lib")  "NET35")

    Add-ToolFolder $folder

where failed function is placed inside Utils.psm1:
    function Get-RelativePath([System.String] $basePath, [System.String] $targetPath)
    {
        # not a general purpose relative path calculation algorithm
        
        return ($targetPath.Substring($basePath.Length)).TrimStart([System.Io.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)
    }

however, I'm not sure yet what's exacly wrong here. Any help would be appriciated.
